# How to get the requests in a queue for a WCF service

Tags: wcf

I have a WCF service hosted as Windows Service.
Nothing fancy InstanceContextMode and ConcurrencyMode is set to Single.

I know there is a default queuing mechanism that WCF uses because I can see that all the requests sent to the service are getting processed.

My question is this, is there a way to know at any particular instance the requests in the queue?

Basically I am looking at getting the requests in the queue and maybe log them to a file for a given instance.

Regards.